# How to binding from List to DataTable then to DataGridView in VB.NET

Tags: list, vb.net, datatable, datagridview, binding

How to binding from List to DataTable then to DataGridView in VB.NET?

The code below I can only bind from DataTable to DataGridView please guide so that I can bind from List to DataTable then to DataGridView.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private _myTable As New DataTable()
    Private Sub BindItemDetailList()
        Dim item As New List(Of item())
    End Sub
    Private Sub BindItemDetail()
        If _myTable.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            Dim field() As String = {"No", "Codeproduct"}
            _myTable = DataControl.CreateDataTableDynamic(field)
        End If
        AddColumnsProgrammatically()
        Grid.DataSource = _myTable
    End Sub
    Private Sub FillDataTable(iRow As Integer, ByVal Codeproduct As String)
        Dim row As DataRow = _myTable.NewRow()
        row("No") = iRow
        row("Codeproduct") = Codeproduct
        _myTable.Rows.Add(row)
    End Sub
    Private Sub AddColumnsProgrammatically()
        Dim Col1 = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        Dim Col2 = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        Col1.HeaderText = "No"
        Col1.Name = "Column1"
        Col1.DataPropertyName = "No"
        Col2.HeaderText = "CodeProduct"
        Col2.Name = "Column2"
        Col2.DataPropertyName = "CodeProduct"
        Grid.Columns.AddRange(New DataGridViewColumn() {Col1, Col2})
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        _myTable.Columns.Add("No", GetType(Integer))
        _myTable.Columns.Add("Codeproduct", GetType(String))
        BindItemDetail()
    End Sub
    End Class
Public Class DataControl
        Public Shared Function CreateDataTableDynamic(ByVal field() As String) As DataTable
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim dtTable As New DataTable("MyTable")
            For i = 0 To field.GetUpperBound(0)
                dtTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(field(i)))
            Next i
            Return dtTable
        End Function
    End Class
    Public Class item
        Public Property No() As Integer
        Public Property CodeProduct() As String
    End Class
```

Comment: There is no binding between a `List(Of T)` and a `DataTable`. The whole point of data binding is to link the UI, i.e. one or more controls, to a data source. Your UI is the `DataGridView`. It's up to you to decide whether to bind it to a `List(Of T)` or a `DataTable`. That's it, that's all.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , Thank you for your reply. Do I have to use an extension that converts from list to datatable?

Comment: There are many examples of extension methods that convert from a List(Of T) to a datatable, but the question is why?  Just bind your DataGridView directly to the List and skip the complication.  I would almost go as far to say working with Lists simplifies some things over using DataTables.

Comment: It's odd to convert from a generic List to a DataTable. It would be more common to go the other way. Why exactly do you want to in the first place? This sounds like an XY problem. You may be trying to solve a problem that you created yourself by solving a different problem in the wrong way.

Comment: There are some things that a standard List can't do with regards to data binding. That's why the BindingList exists. Maybe you should be using that instead. We can only guess though.